# Django can't save new instance to model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I cannot save the data taken from the form to database. The form is displayed properly and it seems that I can submit. Whenever I was redirected to "project_list.html", I cannot see the new project.

I also checked the admin site to whether new instance is saved to model but it seems that something is wrong with my code.

Here is my files:

model.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

view.py

```
def projects_list(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    table = ProjectTable(Project.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page':25}).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'portal/project/list.html', {'projects': 
    projects, 'table': table})


 def project_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('project_list',)
    else:
        form = ProjectAddForm()
    return render(request, 'portal/project/add.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project

class ProjectAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_id', 'project_name',]
```

add.html

```
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add Project{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 text-center">
    <form action="{% url 'portal:projects_list' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>        
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

projects_list.html

```
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}


{% block content %}
    <h1>Projects List</h1>

    {% render_table table %}

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'portal'

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
   path('password_generator/', views.password_generator, 
         name='password_generator'), 
   path('projects_list/', views.projects_list, name='projects_list'),
   path('project/<str:project_id>/', views.project_detail, 
         name='project_detail'),
   path('add/', views.project_add, name='project_add'),
]
```

Comment: try this: `project = form.save(commit=False)` and then `project_name = form.cleaned_data['project_name']` and then save `project.save()`

Comment: @Ahtisham I have tried that but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: where is `project_list` ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I have added the urls.py in the original post. you can check it out

Comment: not urls I need `project_list` view

Comment: @Ahtisham sorry... I also added project_list view

Comment: what is `ProjectTable` ? where is it defined ?

Comment: also update your question with `project_list.html`

Comment: @Ahtisham I also added the list.html. But I dont understand why it is related to issue. May be I am wrong but it seems to me that form cannot save the data to model. I can not see no instance added on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my code. In my project_add view, I was trying to redirect to "project_list" url but it didnt exists. That was the mistake....

Comment: No, its plural.